# Very Slow Aggregate Query on AWS Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, amazon-aurora

I have a table with 12 million rows. One is "aircraft_type" VARCHAR and another one is "speed" DOUBLE. I have an index on "aircraft_type".The following query takes forever on AWS Aurora MySQL (db.r4.large):

```
SELECT aircraft_type, avg(speed) as avg_speed FROM operations GROUP BY aircraft_type;
```

Is such a query unreasonable or am I missing something?

Comment: _"I have a table with 12 million rows..."_  What do you mean by "very slow?"  This is a large table, it's likely going to be somewhat sluggish for this type of query

Comment: Killed it after waiting 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm evaluating AWS Athena and the same query is performed in 3 seconds. I'm just wondering if I'm doing something wrong using AWS Aurora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the EXPLAIN output for that query?
Try adding this index (a covering index) which can be helpful:

```
ALTER TABLE `operations` ADD INDEX `operations_idx_type_speed` (`aircraft_type`,`speed`);
```

Comment: This index certainly helped reduce the processing time drastically to within a few seconds.